# Why can't I see the invoking method in the debugger?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

a beginner question about xCode debugger.

```
- (void)searchDidFinished:(NSDictionary *)info
```

method is invoked and I'm trying to determine who is the invoker but as you can see the call stack doesn't help me: http://cl.ly/AaE4

Why ?

I've also checked if the method is linked in Interface Builder. But this is not the case.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the selector is being called via `performSelectorOnMainThread:` or `performSelector:afterDelay` in which case you won't be able to see the original caller.

Comment: Indeed thanks. I've just searched for it in the project. Is there an easier way to find the invoking method rather than manually search for it ?